# Using .average with .pluck in ruby on rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my app I want to see the average paper use weight for my users which registers to the `Heavy`class.

The `user` model `has_many :papers` and the `paper` model `belongs_to :user`

here is what I got so far: `@heavy_users_testing = User.where(industry_type: 'Heavy').joins(:papers).where("papers.paper_type = 'Officepaper'").pluck(:paper_weight)`

I'm not sure where to but the `active record .average` to get the average Officepaper weight for users in the Heavy category?

Can someone advise me please?

Comment: Do you need average for all users or average for each user?

Comment: I need an average paper weight for the `officepaper` type, for all users which have the indusrty_type `Heavy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the sql `avg` function inside `pluck`

```
@heavy_users_testing = User.where(industry_type: 'Heavy')
  .joins(:papers)
  .where(papers: { paper_type: 'Officepaper' } )
  .pluck('avg(paper_weight)')
```

If you want/need the average for EACH user, you need to do a `group`

```
@heavy_users_testing = User.where(industry_type: 'Heavy')
  .joins(:papers)
  .where(papers: { paper_type: 'Officepaper' } )
  .group(:user_id)
  .pluck('avg(paper_weight)')
```

Comment: It seems to work, but in the `<%= @heavy_users_testing %>` the Output is displayed as `[#<BigDecimal:7ffa497d5f50,'0.15E2',9(27)>]` I´ve tried to put `.to_f`at the end of the code and also to `@heavy_users_testing` but it gives an error

Comment: It's an array, `pluck` always returns an array. So you would have to do `@heavy_users_testing.first.to_f`, or add `.....pluck(..).first`

Comment: Ok I get it, that makes sence, but how is it then possible to get the average of all paper_weight for all users in the Heavy class?  The use of `.first` is only showing the first part of the array, right?

Comment: It's only one value, because it's showing average for all users. That is what you said you wanted.

Comment: If you need the average for EACH user, you need to do a `group`

Comment: You're right, average for all users is what I wanted and I got it... thanks for the help