# ActiveRecord: treat nil as a 0 in calculations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using this code in my controller to access the average `paper_weight` for all my users in the `Heavy` classification.

```
if User.where(industry_type: 'Heavy')
 .joins(:papers)
 .where(papers: { paper_type: 'Officepaper' } )
 .pluck('avg(paper_weight)').first.nil?
 @heavy_indust_officepaper == 0
else
@heavy_indust_officepaper = User.where(industry_type: 'Heavy')
 .joins(:papers)
 .where(papers: { paper_type: 'Officepaper' } )
 .pluck('avg(paper_weight)').first * 3 
end
```

Then the variable `@heavy_indust_officepaper` is displayed in a view.

The problem is that this code above doesn't seem to be calculating the average  correctly  when one or more users have a `nil` entry in `paper_type: 'Officepaper'` .

I know that because I have two users in the `industry_type: 'Heavy'`
One of them has one entry of `paper_type: 'Officepaper'` which is the decimal 30. 
And the other user has `nil` entry in `paper_type: 'Officepaper'`.

By my understanding the calculation should be `30 + 0 / 2(users) = 15`

and then the `15`is multiplied by `3` which should give `45`

But instead the variable `@heavy_indust_officepaper` is displaying `90`in the view... which must be the result of `30 * 3`

Is there a way to convert the `nil`to `0` with in the code above???

Please Can some one advise me?

Here is a link to a question I asked earlier to day, I got help with this code from it [Using .average with .pluck in ruby on rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43514890/using-average-with-pluck-in-ruby-on-rails-app/43515154?noredirect=1#comment74085001_43515154)

Comment: did you try `nil.to_i`? try it in `irb`... than maybe use `.first.to_i * 3 ` ... just a thought...

Comment: Why are you running the same query twice instead of using a local variable?

Comment: Hello, maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220449/sql-avg-with-null-values will help you

Comment: Please, make sure to select and accept an answer if within given ones there is such that solved your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is (among others) is your misunderstanding of what `pluck` does. It returns you an array of average *someting* for every user. So in your example it returns you

```
[30, nil]
```

That's why you get `90` (`[30, nil].first * 30` => `90`).

To get average for all users, use [`average`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average).

---

Solution:

You can use `COALESCE` to convert `NULL` to zero while calculating average:

```
User.where(industry_type: 'Heavy')
    .joins(:papers)
    .where(papers: { paper_type: ['Officepaper', nil] } )
    .average('COALESCE(papers.paper_weight, 0)') * 3
#=> 15
```

One thing to be aware of is that while `COALESCE` will convert any `null` value to `0` while calculating, `average` will still return `nil` if there *were no* records to calculate `average` on.

How to handling this case is for you to decide, but **@max** already has shown one of the pretty straightforward options (assuming that above query results is written to `average` variable):

```
average.nil? ? 0 : average * 3
```

Comment: Good answer but you still need to check for nil. "Calculates the average value on a given column. Returns nil if there's no row." http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average

Answer (score 1):

```
avg = User.where(industry_type: 'Heavy')
 .joins(:papers)
 .where(papers: { paper_type: ['Officepaper', nil] } )
 .average('papers.paper_weight')

@heavy_indust_officepaper = avg.nil? ? 0 : avg * 3
```

Comment: It would be a bit more concise to say `avg ? avg * 3 : 0`.

Comment: @moveson `avg&.* 3` is even more concise, but I think shortness is not the main point :)

Comment: Agreed, but if you are going to go to the trouble of having a ternary, I figure you might as well get rid of the extra method call. I try not to use `#nil?` unless it leads to a clearly better result as compared to relying on the inherent falsiness of the variable that evaluates to `nil`.

Comment: @moveson as @AndreyDeineko already stated  shortness is not the point. Rather the `.nil?` call is just to make it abundantly obvious that whats going on is a nil check.

Comment: I understand that shortness is not the point. I'm merely suggesting a style that is both cleaner and [recommended](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-non-nil-checks) in the Ruby style guide.